Mi funcion checkAndExpireSubscription no expira la suscripcion porque no cumple la condicion del suscriptionExpirated en firebase con suscriptionDate
La funcion expiredSuscription funciona si la llamo directamente pero no se ejecuta si depende de checkAndExpireSuscription
 Future<void> checkAndExpireSubscription(String userId) async {
      //OBTENER DATOS DEL USUARIO POR EL ID
      final userDoc =
          await _firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get();
      if (userDoc.exists) {
        final userData = userDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (userData.containsKey('subscriptionExpirated') &&
            userData['subscriptionExpirated'] is Timestamp) {
          final subscriptionExpirated =
              (userData['subscriptionExpirated'] as Timestamp).toDate();
          final now = (userData['subscriptionDate'] as Timestamp).toDate();

          if (subscriptionExpirated.compareTo(now) < 0) {
            await expireSubscription(userId);
          } else {
            print('Suscripción sigue activa');
          }
        }
      }
  }

